# Make indexable an ajax based webpage

Tags: html, ajax, indexing, url-rewriting

I want to make indexable my ajax based website.

I have read this doc: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started But I don't understand it at all.

I think I need to do it:

1. Write this tag in a webpage, for example: www.myweb.com/mypage

   ```
   <meta name="fragment" content="!">
   ```
2. I'm using UrlRewriteFilter for my Tomcat Server (http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/), so I think I could redirect the urls with the substring: "?_escaped_fragment_=" to a html snapshot (which I can build manually, writing my custom meta-description, title and content???)

   ```
   <rule>
      <from>^/mypage\?_escaped_fragment_=</from>
      <to type="forward">/snapshots/mypage.html</to>
   </rule>
   ```
3. Write the URLs (without the escaped fragment) into the sitemap.xml

   ```
   ...
   <url>
   <loc>www.myweb.com/mypage</loc>
   ...
   </url>
   ...
   ```

Is it right? I need to do something more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it is right, but the UrlRewriteFilter syntax is a bit different:

```
<rule>

    <condition name="_escaped_fragment_" type="parameter" operator="equal"></condition>

    <from>^/mypage/</from>

    <to last="true">/snapshots/mypage.html</to>

</rule>
```